# Large off-screen tables with actions

Tags: tables

here is a new question for my fellow colleagues.

I am creating a framework and trying to standardize table creation, so I have to take under consideration all possible scenarios and am between decisions concerning large tabular data that expand off-screen with multiple row-actions.

I have already created two flavours of tables for small screens, either the table is scrollable off-screen or have a collapsible version of stacked cells.

---

[image]

- **Collapsible version**. The vertical ellipsis icon includes row actions in a popover.

However, since our applications are using HUGE tabular data  (like 100+ columns) and some of the rows have actions that cannot be translated into distinguishable icons (e.g. Flood reporting) I have to come up with a solution for large tabular data with many actions in text format. Stacking this kind of volume of data vertically is out of the question, so a solution has to be found for the scrollable version of the table.

---

[image]

- **Scrollable table**

However, it is obvious that it is bad UX for a row to have actions off-screen. Keep in mind that these rows will probably have to be selectable as well.

I have thought of creating a fixed column with a popover on the right, but am not really fond of this solution; adding to the previous comment, imho, checkboxes should always be on the left of the row, so having two fixed columns - one on the left for checkboxes and one on the right for actions feels wrong. Having checkboxes and actions on the right feels even worse.

So, the best scenario I could think of, that is somewhat limiting, is to have a 'multi-select' icon off-screen, only appearing on small screen resolutions so that the checkbox row only appears on-demand.

---

I am wondering what kind of ideas do you guys have? I would like to avoid any swipe-related solutions due to these feel natural only on specific sets of devices.

Comment: These actions are in columns for themselves (or an icon inside a field)? How many of these action columns will there be?

Comment: They should be placed in their own column. There is no restriction to the number of the actions or text width  - there is great variety of actions, so I am trying to think of the worst case scenario.

Comment: So, just to clarify, the actions will apply to the whole row, not to a particular field?

Comment: Yes, they should apply for the whole row.

Comment: Backing up a bit: Is there a use case for needing to access the actions on a huge table of data on a mobile screen? While I understand that you're trying to build out a framework, this seems like a scenario where something custom should be created if mobile usage is high priority.

Comment: Mobile use is required by specifications. Additionally, I personally hate interfaces, when mobile doesn't have full functionality compared to desktop alternatives.. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is what I went with, and I find it a once-and-for-all solution for long tables that contain actions or multi-item actions.

If the problem was either solely mobile-oriented or desktop-oriented it would have been much easier since users depending on the device they are expecting different interfaces. In order for the design to make sense here is what was designed.

This is what the table looks like on a desktop device. If the actions are small, or icons are used, they can be expanded, for more actions the solution is a dropdown menu.

[image]

...as soon the table is larger than its parent overflown container and using javascript, shadows are added to the checkboxes and fixed actions column to indicate that their position is fixed and that the rest of the table is scrollable.

[image]

...when the table starts scrolling out of view, the header of the table stays fixed, and a shadow is added to indicate this as shown:

[image]

...following responsive principles, below a certain width, the multi-actions dropdown is essentially turned in a vertical ellipsis menu that contains the options.

The header multi-item actions:

[image]

The single-item actions:

[image]

For performance reasons, the fixed header on mobile is limited just to the item count and multi-action dropdown menu, since mobile devices cannot handle without performance decrease the re-positioning of the fixed table header cells. To be honest, I never saw a fixed header of an overflown table working on mobile properly, not even on applications, so, since it is not common, I find it more than acceptable to avoid it for mobile use.

[image]

Needless to say, it was a nightmare to make it work on all devices without noticing performance issues, while keeping its functionality the same along all browsers and devices, with the exception of the fixed scrolling header removal for mobile devices. I spent a lot of time on this one, and has been an issue that hasn't been dealt successfully forever - at least according to my standards, so I thought I'd share and (hopefully) make some of you happy, since it is is a cross-browser, cross-device solution that works great (tested on various devices - blackberry, windows phone, iphone, ipad, android mobile, android tablet) without performance issues. Enjoy!

Comment: Very nice solution you ended up with, thanks for sharing :) I was thinking maybe to improve the performance you could [remove the shadows](http://nerds.airbnb.com/box-shadows-are-expensive-to-paint/)? Also for the opened menu, another option is to [open it without the "close" button](https://material.io/guidelines/components/menus.html#menus-usage).

Comment: The shadows performance impact is not even visible, not even on my 50euro windows phone device. They render really fast - just for a heads-up, there is a also a trick with shadows, you can put them on an :after pseudo element with opacity:0 and change to opacity:1 when needed, so the heavy performance-wise shadows are rendered once and you play with cheap performance-wise opacity. I avoid the 'without' close solutions because the user might feel 'obligated' to click on an action, while they might click to any other part of the screen to close that might contain a link.

Comment: Nice solution though I expected you to keep the multiple actions in an action bar that would float above the fixed table header instead of repeating it per row.

Comment: What you are saying suggests that this multi-action bar is also visible on desktop screens as well... imagine viewing a table on a desktop that has enough space to fit its row actions but instead it has an action bar above it. Wouldn't that be confusing to users and waste of usable  space?

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion **the way of displaying the data should adapt to the device where it is being displayed**. Because users interact differently on each device. So my first suggestion is to give a reconsideration to non-scrollable (in X axis) solution for touch devices with small screens.

[image]

If you need a scrollable solution this my suggestion:

- Keep Column name row always visible
- Hide all the actions, behind a Menu always accessible. The Element row menu includes actions related to that row, while the Column row includes actions to apply to several rows.

[image]
..
[image]
..
[image]

If you need to apply an action to several rows at one time, in order to avoid the first image, include a menu icon (perhaps different to the row ones) in the Columns row with several actions that would need to select rows.

[image]

[image]
..
[image]

Resources:

[Material design - Data tables](https://material.io/guidelines/components/data-tables.html#)

Comment: I like your answer. Was going to suggest almost the same thing, but I'd have rather kept the checkbox out of the action menu as it would otherwise make the concept of simultaneously selecting multiple rows senseless and all the more tedious if you have to click twice to select each row.

Comment: You are right, Ill clarify that. Adding that extra column adds even more fixed elements. But if the selection is important then it must be there I guess.

Comment: The menu could also be incorporated in a context menu on right click sort of fashion, the way google drive does. On mobile one could go for a click and hold for context menu.

Comment: @ikartik90 you mean press anywhere in the row to display? It frees up space but the bad thing is new users might become crazy looking for the menu icon.

Comment: True that. New users might struggle a bit with it but it could be overcome with a small onboarding guide screen for newcomers. That way you would free up screen space, make the interface clean and the users won't be left unaware to fend for themselves.

Comment: @Alvaro first of all I really don't get a few things on material design. Most people are right handed so they are expected to see the actions on the right hand side. Concerning the lists of enormous data, the stacked table cell content doesn't help much since the whole reason behind tabular data is comparison. I don't get the second example though - are you suggesting, clicking on a menu, to then enable checkboxes and then select items? How would you trigger the multi-item action then?

Comment: @scooterlord You are right about menus being on the right side usually, but as most people are right handed it might be more comfortable to have the fixed column on the left.

Comment: @scooterlord As the Checkboxes are used for applying a certain action to more than one item, the proposal is: Displaying common actions in the Header row. Once selected the action the checkboxes appear, user selects and after clicks the apply or cancel button.

Comment: @Alvaro so, this requires that a third set of actions are needed... 'apply' or 'cancel'. Do you feel this a good user experience? :/ man, when did our work become so difficult? :/

Comment: @scooterlord haha, well just an idea that might help you figure out something better for your case. Probably others can bring better proposals, let's wait :)

Comment: @Alvaro you have provided great food for though bro, don't get me wrong. I am breaking my head myself. If I had a better solution I wouldn't be asking here, right?

Comment: Hey.. any other ideas? :D

Comment: @scooterlord What problems do you find with the current proposal?

Comment: @Alvaro a user's mind would never go as far to understand that they have to click on button located at the top RIGHT of a table header in order to initiate multi-select. Users expect to see checkboxes and afterwards initiate their actions. Moreover this is not just a mobile issue, so we can't think the 'mobile way' because there might be long rows with many columns that push actions out of the screen as well - you can't expect desktop users to use this logic.

Comment: @scooterlord the thing is normally rows don't have in-row actions. Fields have actions. Actions are applied from the header of the Table so first the user selects several rows and then applies the action found in the header. Is this last approach a better option for your case?

Comment: @Alvaro, I have already designed what you said. The more I am working on it the more I believe that tables cannot be standardized. :/ You can't predict table width, table column number, table cell content size, number of actions. For example, the solution you are proposing would make sense to mobile users but what would happen on desktops? What if there was only one action per row and the whole table would fit on screen? Would it feel natural to have actions on the header? :/

Answer (score 2):

I dealt with a similar scenario working for one of our clients who had a similar situation. This is how I dealt with the problem:

[image: Rows listed on left with selected row detailed on the right]

I listed the table rows with the primarily required columns, that the users referred the most, directly visible to them. When a user wished to see a row's information in detail, they would click on the row and the right side fixed pane would pop out that was independently scrollable vertically within its bounds. On mobile, the number of columns of the main table would shrink as the size degraded and the right pane would pop out from the bottom of the screen as the user tapped on it. The actions pertaining to the row (eg. Edit record here) are listed in the right pane as the user clicks the particular row.

[image: Row information displayed in an accordion]

Another variant I had presented was displaying the data in an accordion like table, as @Alvaro has suggested above. The only issue with this one is that the table columns form a grid sort of a structure leading to the hampering of the overall readability of data.

Comment: I don't see any solution to the multi-select issue though..

Comment: ..I see an 'export all' button at the bottom, but this design doesn't help on Iphones where clicking at the bottom of the page, the safari action row appears so you have to click twice..

Comment: @scooterlord For iPhone, you could open a collapsible widget of actions from the right end of the screen listening for any actions on multiselect.

Comment: however the application we design should not be device-specific, so it has to look the same on all devices, so all device limitations have to be taken under consideration and functionality should be the same

Answer (score 1):

Chris Coyier has published a table design where in the mobile version "each row is its own table":

[image]

Maybe this design could be useful for you. With that, it might be more easy to accommodate the action buttons for each "row".

In the mobile version, you could even make the rows collapsible in relation to a (user selected?) specific "column header". For example, while scrolling down you only see the last names and you only expand the full "row"-data, if you are interested.

Sources:

https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php (DEMO: reduce browser width to see the effect)

https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/

https://www.digitalgov.gov/2014/10/28/trends-on-tuesday-8-ways-to-format-tables-for-responsive-web-design/

Comment: I have seen these pages a million times. This still does not provide a solution to my problem concerning actions in a long row of data inside a scrollable table, that might be in a column that is off-screen.